# IE10 User agent sting displaying trident 5 instead of 6

Tags: user-agent, internet-explorer-10

Recently we encountered one of our customers encountering problems loading one of our secure pages. Then all of a sudden the problems disappeared.

The customer recently upgraded IE9 to IE10 on Win7.  When he was having a problem the user agent string indicated "trident/5.0". When the problem appeared to resolve itself, the only difference in the user string was "trident/6.0"

Is this a problem or am I barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Can you paste the page's doctype please?

Comment: Here is some info about the new IE10 user agent string: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/15/the-ie10-user-agent-string.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the information, after further trouble shooting with the customer. It appeared that he had not properly installed IE10.